# How to open big files in a text editor written in C

Tags: c, memory

I wonder how i can read big files with C

I am quite sure that you can use: fopen().
I wrote a text editor with fopen() and if I try to open a 10GB txt file it says: KILLED.

So my assumption is to use shm_open such that we can access shared memory. I dont need a code, I just wonder if my assumption with shm_open is correct. And if not what could be a solution?

Comment: Read part of it at a time.

Comment: And maybe get [more creative](https://iq.opengenus.org/rope-data-structure/#:~:text=A%20Rope%20data%20structure%20is,comparison%20to%20a%20traditional%20String.) about how you manage a text file that large.

Comment: Opening is not a problem. The problem is where you store the content you are reading and how much at a time.

Comment: @TomKarzes what do you mean by the default dynamic data size limit? Does the OS limits the reading?

Comment: You could use `mmap()`. I suspect that's what you meant when you asked about shared memory.

Comment: @Barmar yes that was it the mmap() ! You are right

Comment: Once I wrote a text editor for big files. The key was to keep in ram only the modified text, and fetching non-modified text always from disk (with some caching).

Comment: A rope is a great container for this sort of thing, especially if you implement it with virtual sections (that is, allow for some portions of the file to be represented as some sort of not-yet-read node).